# Chrome: Auto-run for Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, browser, userscripts, tampermonkey

Does anybody know if there is some way to run a piece of Javascript code for each page that loads in a browser? Sort of like inserting `<script>` first thing inside the `head` tag. I am most interested in a solution for Chrome. Maybe that is a job for a Chrome extension?

Comment: Do you mean for any web page, or just one you can modify the source for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo), it's a Chrome extension for running user scripts (equivalent to GreaseMonkey for FF). To run a script on every page, you'd have a line like this near the beginning of your script:

```
// @include     *
```

Here's a [tutorial](http://greasemonkey.mozdev.org/authoring.html) on writing user scripts.

Comment: Looks promising. Do you know how Tampermonkey does the trick, i.e. telling Chrome to always load the script?

Comment: @JonasN not sure exactly, but [Chrome APIs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html) do give you a lot of control.

Comment: Got my first script going (alert('Tampermonkey Script!') :) ), so this is a verified solution. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, there is a selector "Run at:" in the Settings gui with the options of "document-start", "document-body" and "document-end". "document-end" seems to be the pre-selected alternative.

Comment: @JonasN that makes sense to me because people mostly use user scripts to "fix" things on pages or add new functionality. You'd want the script to run at the end so that the DOM exists.